# First entrance time for an integer-valued stochastic process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $N_t$ be an almost surely cadlag $\mathbb{N}$-valued stochastic process. Fix $M \in \mathbb{N}$ and define the stopping time 
$T := \inf\{t \geq 0: \, N_t \geq M \} $. Suppose that $T$ is almost surely finite.

Is it true that $N_T \geq M$ almost surely?

Comment: This is almost obvious. What makes you suspect that it might not be true?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Since $T=\inf\{t:N_t\ge M\}$, for each $k\in\mathbb N$ there is a $t_k\in [T,T+1/k)$ with $N_{t_k}\ge M$. Since $\{N_t\}$ is right continuous, $$N_T=\lim_{k\to\infty}N_{t_k}\ge M.$$